# Should I use individual vocabulary files for each tensorflow categorical column?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

Is there a reason to use a different vocab list for each feature column rather than giving every feature column the same "global" vocab list?

For instance, let's say I was building a DNN with Tensorflow's DNNClassifier estimator to determine whether a cat is "awesome" or "lame".

Each feature column is a categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file wrapped in an indicator_column.

Column 1 might be "Birth Month" with options "January", "February", etc.

Column 2 is "Coloration" with options "Calico" or "Tabby".

Column 3 is "Likes Cheese" with options "Yes" or "No".

I make "global_vocab_list.txt" a list of every month as well as:

Calico

Tabby

Yes

No

And use that same list as the vocab file for every feature column.

Will Tensorflow give me meaningfully different results if instead I pass "month_vocab_list.txt" to the "Birth Month" feature column, "coloration_vocab_list.txt" to the "Coloration" feature column, and 
"yes_no_vocab.txt" to the "Likes Cheese" feature column? Would there perhaps be a performance increase with one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some individual files. According to the Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file), in `categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file`, there are no args capable of what you described.

> - `vocabulary_file`: The vocabulary file name.
> - `vocabulary_size`: Number of the elements in the vocabulary. This must be no greater than length of vocabulary_file, if less than
>     length, later values are ignored. If None, it is set to the length of
>     vocabulary_file.
> - `num_oov_buckets`: Non-negative integer, the number of out-of-vocabulary buckets. All out-of-vocabulary inputs will be
>     assigned IDs in the range [vocabulary_size,
>     vocabulary_size+num_oov_buckets) based on a hash of the input value. A
>     positive num_oov_buckets can not be specified with default_value.
> - `default_value`: The integer ID value to return for out-of-vocabulary feature values, defaults to -1. This can not be
>     specified with a positive num_oov_buckets.